# Reg: wdio Common locators between iOS and Android native app, developed using ReactNative (Apart from AccessibilityID)

Tags: react-native, appium, webdriver-io

Reg: wdio Common locators between iOS and Android native app, developed using ReactNative (Apart from AccessibilityID)

Hi, 
We are developing test automation framework for ReactNative App (iOS & Android combined) using WebdriverIO+Appium.
*There's NO webview, its pure ReactNative iOS & Android app*

1. In terms of locator strategy, are there common webdriverIO locators between iOS & Android (apart from Accessbility ID)?
   REf: [WebdriverIO docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html)
2. Also, we are in the initial stage of framework development; We are exploring to have a possibility to have a single page-object for both IOS & Android.
   a) Will it be possible or we need to have separate page objects?
   b) or is there way to get Android / iOS context & based on the context have different locator strategy, where common locator strategy (Accessibility ID) is not workable.
3. How to get current App type using, webdriverIO's **browser** or **$** or **$$** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, standard Appium based mobile XPath constructs are possible.

```
let elem = driver.element("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name=\"Username\"]");
element.click();
```

Also, as per webdriverIO documentation, we should be able to find the platform type as below:

```
    // Note: `driver` is the equivalent to the `browser` object but semantically more correct
// you can choose which global variable you want to use
console.log(driver.isMobile); // outputs: true
console.log(driver.isIOS); // outputs: true
console.log(driver.isAndroid); // outputs: false
```

link: [WDIO official Reference](https://webdriver.io/docs/browserobject.html)

Comment: Similar issue: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17214/can-selenium-driver-detect-which-platform-it-is-running-in